# Enable multi search without filter button in sxa check list filter

Tags: search-facet, sxa-search

I am using sxa check list filter functionality. For multiple categories the filter button is coming automatically, can anyone pls help to enable the multiple filter without button.
It seems that I need to change the JS code in searchfilter, but I am not able to do it.
Thanks

Comment: Can you hide the button with css?

Comment: I can hide but multi filter  will not work

Answer (score 1):

You will have to modify `component-search-results-filter.js` file.

There is `if (properties.multi)` inside `updateFacet` function.

If you will look inside there is another `if`

```jss
if (currentFacet[0].type == "button") {
    for (i = 0; i < sig.length; i++) {
        // updating hash here
    }
    queryModel.updateHash(hash); // this is what should be called to cause results to reload
}
```

You can remove this `if` condition and it will work (leave the logic specified inside in place). What you want is to invoke this logic for ever case, not just **Filter** button.

In a normal scenario when you click on a **Filter** button this condition in the if returns `true`. In your case, when you click on a facet name it is just a `<p>` element

Comment: Could you please help me to apply to specific page instead of affecting whole site by extending this?we have multiple languages sites so of I will change the Base theme it will affect other sites as well

Comment: First option: Make a copy of the Search Theme, modify scripts, assign the custom Search theme to your site theme/ page (whole site or just page using a theme to page design mapping, and then assign design explicitly to your page)
The other option I can see (to apply to a single page) is to create a custom MetaPartial rendering where you will overwrite the function in your custom JSS injected into the page.
Third option. Add a script to your theme to overwrite the behavior in search rendering but do it only when a particular body class is present (body class can be set on any page)